# Какая реализация базы данных работает лучше всего на рисунке ниже?

Tags: sql, база-данных

У компании есть фиксированный реестр должностей, для каждого из которых есть фиксированная зарплата. Сотрудник может занять только одну позицию за раз. Как мне лучше ее реализовать?

[image: Структура БД]

[Структура БД (Google Doc)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwpsmnL_26VNRE03QXVhX09FSE0/view)

Comment: Картинка не открывается, исправьте вопрос, что бы все было в вопросе

Comment: Исправил. Спасибо.

Comment: Голосую за 3, т.к. универсальна, правда запросы будут тяжелее/дольше. Если все по быстрому и на коленке, то 1.

Comment: Если за раз, может быть только 1 позиция и это никогда не изменится, то 2 лучше всего подходит, т.к. отсутствуют лишние таблицы (соответственно место не тратится впустую) и компоненты независимы друг от друга, что позволит легко редактировать в будущем структуры.

Comment: 3 таблица совершенно излишня. Вторая - да.

Comment: Вторая однозначна. Не плодите лишних таблиц, не провоцируйте хлам.

Comment: Непонятна сама логика - у вас зарплата на должность распределяется? или именно для каждого человека может быть вообще разная (даже с совпадающими должностями)?

Comment: В любом случае, если и выбирать первую схему - то имеет смысл заменить тип `position` с `varchar` на `enum`.

Answer (score 2):

Вариант 1 - денормализован, так делать не надо, в будущем у вас могут появиться, и скорее всего появятся дополнительные свойства, например отдел к которому причислена позиция или вид ставки повременная/сдельная и т.д.

Вариант 3 - предполагает отношение "многие ко многим", что противоречит условиям задачи.

Поэтому наиболее правильным будет, ИМХО, вариант 2. Хотя и в этом случае, лично я, отбил бы оплату в отдельную таблицу, кроме того что она может меняться во времени, бывают и разные виды ставок, кроме того, разные ставки по разному облагаются налогами - это раз. И ссылался не в таблице работников на таблицу позиций, а в таблице позиций на работника, по условиям задачи у нас фиксированный реестр должностей, но не списочный состав - это два.